# White flower with spikes around base?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

[image]

What type of flower is this? 
Location : India

Comment: Where (country / region, ecosystem) did you find it? What is the approximate size? What did the rest of the plant look like (size, appearance of the leaves, branches, etc...)? What other info can you give us?

Answer (score 3):

This does in fact look like the flower to the cactus species [***Selenicereus grandiflorus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenicereus_grandiflorus).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Selenicereus_grandiflorus3.jpg)</sup>

According to ["Indigenous Cactus biodiversity: A viable genetic resource to fulfill multiform needs under rainfed ecosystems"](http://www.niscair.res.in/sciencecommunication/researchjournals/rejour/ijtk/fulltextsearch/2011/January%202011/IJTK-Vol%2010(1)-January%202011-pp%20194-197.htm)<sup>1</sup>, this plant is found in India:

> Different varieties of the cactus are found in India which has immense ethnomedicinal value (Table 1). **Selenicereus grandiflorus** (with large sweet-scented night flowering flowers) and the Opuntia stricta are found in the wasteland as hedge plants

See [here](https://www.fotocommunity.de/photo/koenigin-der-nacht-j-stolzenberg/3442844) for a good image, and see [here](http://stolzenberg.bplaced.net/kdn2.gif) for a cool gif of one of these flowers blooming!

---

<sup>1. Rai, M., Singh, R.K., Sharma, P.C. and Singh, L.K., 2011. Indigenous Cactus biodiversity: A viable genetic resource to fulfill multiform needs under rainfed ecosystems.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This could be Selenicereus grandiflorus, the Queen of the Night.

Comment: Welcome & thanks for your post. Species ID answers should be accompanied by credible sources confirming that ID, a picture of the species from a credible source and background information confirming the species (geographical spread, habitat, ...)